# Vue have 2 class conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, react-fullstack

I am trying to learn vue and all about classes and having them be dynamic. I have an issue that I can't seem to find the solution for. I have a div and in it I want to have a class that depends on a variable such like this

`<div :class="{'active':isActive}"`

but for the same div I also wan to have another class name that is in the data for the vue component. Such like this

`<div :class="divTheme"`

So basically together it would look something like this

`<div :class="{'active':isActive} :class="divTheme"`

but I understand that you cannot have two classes that are like this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class binding supports [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax), and you can further use object syntax inside array syntax as follows in your case:

```
<div :class="[{'active': isActive}, divTheme]"
```